# Decimal T-SQL to Decimal C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, decimal

Is it possible to get a potential problem with conversion of a T-SQL `decimal(30,8)` to `decimal` in C#?

Comment: @Alex but what about accuracy of T-SQL decimal ? Where the limit of conversion overflow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't represent all possible values of `decimal(30,8)` with the `System.Decimal` type of .NET.

`decimal(30,8)` has 30 significant digits, `System.Decimal` has 28-29 according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

For example `1234567890123456789012.12345678` is a valid value for `decimal(30,8)`, but writing `1234567890123456789012.12345678m` in C# returns `1234567890123456789012.1234568`, rounded and missing a digit.